# feed_dict in TensorFlow throwing unexpected error (summary operations)

Tags: python, tensorflow

My training script, for training a TensorFlow model, very slightly modified from the tutorials online:

```
def train(data_set_dir, train_set_dir):
    data = data_input.read_data_sets(data_set_dir, train_set_dir)

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        # defines placeholders (type=tf.float32)
        images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(batch_size, image_size, channels)

        logits = model.inference(images_placeholder, num_classes)
        loss = loss(logits, labels_placeholder, num_classes)
        train_op = training(loss, global_step, batch_size)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables()) 
        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()  
        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(init)
        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph)

        for step in range(max_steps):
            start_time = time.time()
            feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(data, images_placeholder, labels_placeholder, batch_size)
            _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            # ... continue to print loss_value, run summaries and save checkpoints
```

The placeholder_inputs function called above is:

```
def placeholder_inputs(batch_size, img_size, channels):
    images_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        shape=(batch_size, img_size, img_size, channels), name='images')
    labels_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        shape=(batch_size, img_size, img_size), name='labels')
    return images_pl, labels_pl
```

To clarify, the data I'm dealing with is for per-pixel classification in a segmentation problem. As seen above, this is a binary classification problem.

And the feed_dict function is:

```
def fill_feed_dict(data_set, images_pl, labels_pl, batch_size):
    images_feed, labels_feed = data_set.next_batch(batch_size)
    feed_dict = {images_pl: images_feed, labels_pl: labels_feed}
    return feed_dict
```

Where I'm stuck at:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'labels' with dtype float and shape [1,750,750]
 [[Node: labels = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,750,750], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The traceback reveals it to have been caused by the 'labels' tensor from my `placeholder_inputs` function. Moreover, this error keeps shifting between the two placeholders, as far as I can see - randomly. One time, it is the 'labels' [`labels_pl`] tensor, another time, it is my 'images'[`images_pl`] tensor.

Error in detail:

```
File ".../script.py", line 32, in placeholder_inputs
  shape=(batch_size, img_size, img_size), name='labels')
File ".../tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 895, in placeholder
  name=name)
File ".../tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1238, in _placeholder 
  name=name)
File ".../tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
  op_def=op_def)
File ".../tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
  original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
  self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

What I've tried/checked:

1. Placing the feed_dict out of the for loop, as well, to no avail.
2. Verified that there is enough data in the training data directory to correspond to the batch_size requirements.
3. Multiple variations on specifying the dtype of the placeholders - assuming 'float' was key in the stacktrace.
4. Cross-checked data shapes. They are exactly as specified in the placeholders.

Perhaps this is a much simpler problem than I think it to be. Maybe even a minor typo I just cannot see here. Suggestions? I believe I've exhausted all options. Looking for someone to shed new light on the problem.

I've referred to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError.md) description of the error.

**Update:**

Did a `print feed_dict` before the `session.run` (as suggested in a comment here) and noticed that the expected values are being fed into the placeholder:

```
{<tf.Tensor 'images:0' shape=(1, 750, 750, 3) dtype=float32>:
array([[[[-0.1556225 , -0.13209309, -0.15954407],
     [-0.15954407, -0.12032838, -0.13601466],
     .....
     [-0.03405387,  0.04829907,  0.09535789]]]], dtype=float32),
 <tf.Tensor 'labels:0' shape=(1, 750, 750) dtype=float32>: 
 array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       .....
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)}
```

Also something I didn't mention earlier:
The loop runs for the first time. So, I get an output for the first value of `step = 0` and then proceeds to promptly exit, after printing the `loss_value` statement I specify for `step=0`.

**Update 2:**

I figured where the problem was. It was with printing the `summary_op`. But why this is so is beyond me. This is how I print it in the for loop:

```
if step % 100 == 0:
    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
```

Commenting this block out does the trick. Thoughts on why this is going wrong?

**Update 3: Solved**

Answer below. What I notice though, is that the [TensorFlow CIFAR-10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py) does a similar `sess.run`, without an explicit mention of `feed_dict` and that runs fine. How exactly does it work then?

Comment: Numpy arrays default to `np.float64`, but `DT_FLOAT` is an equivalent of `np.float32`, so maybe add an `.as_type(np.float32)`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov yep, tried that too. Assuming you mean, `astype(np.float32)` on my input arrays to the placeholder.

Comment: maybe add a print before each session.run call to figure out what's the actual shape and dtype that gets fed into the placeholder

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov How exactly could I print the array being fed in before a `session run`? I've only printed them after.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I did a `print feed_dict` as a quick and dirty solution. They seems to be of the expected dtype and shape. Updated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious error.
I didn't specify a `feed_dict` for the session run on `summary_op`.

```
if step % 100 == 0:
    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
```

Explicitly mentioning the `feed_dict` call in the session run did the trick. But why? The TensorFlow CIFAR-10 example does a similar `sess.run`, without this explicit mention of `feed_dict` and that runs fine.

Comment: Oh right, I guess the error message really says that that your fetched output depended on a placeholder which isn't fed. Possible reason why it could work in other scenarios is if it uses `placeholder_with_default`, or when summary doesn't depend on value of placeholder

Comment: That clarifies things. Thanks!